# Facebook Graph API - Video Upload

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

With the REST api in the process of being deprecated, I'm trying to convert our existing application to use the facebook c# sdk.

One of the things we can currently do, is post a video by uploading it.

I've created a POST request as follows, but I'm getting a failure of 'Unsupported Post Request'.

```
            byte[] video = File.ReadAllBytes(TESTDATA_DIR + "Snowboarding penguin.mov");

        if (_FBClient != null)
        {
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters.Add("message", "This is a Graph API unit test message containing a video! (" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ")");
            parameters["caption"] = "This is the caption for the unit test message!";
            parameters["description"] = "This is description for the unit test message!";
            parameters["name"] = "This is name of the unit test message!";
            parameters["req_perms"] = "publish_stream";
            parameters["scope"] = "publish_stream";

            var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                FileName = "Snowboarding penguin.mov",
                ContentType = "video/mov",
            };
            mediaObject.SetValue(video);
            parameters.Add("source", mediaObject);

            _FBClient.Post("me/videos", parameters);
        }
```

I see lots of general posts about video uploading not being supported by the GRAPH API, but hopefully this has been resolved by FB now.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction for getting this request to work?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Video uploading is not supported by the graph api. You will need to use the old rest api.</strike>

```
        var videoPath = "c:\\sample.3gp";
        byte[] video = File.ReadAllBytes(videoPath);

        var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
                              {
                                  FileName = "sample.3gp",
                                  ContentType = "video/3gpp"
                              };
        mediaObject.SetValue(video);

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.source = mediaObject;
        parameters.method = "video.upload";
        parameters.access_token = "access_token";

        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Post(parameters);
```

**UPDATE** 
Facebook recently supported uploading video via graph api. You can find the details on how to use graph api video upload from Facebook C# SDK at http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Uploading-Video-via-Graph-Api.aspx

Requires Facebook C# SDK **v5.0.46** or higher.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token"); 
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = "video/3gpp", FileName = "video.3gp" }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\video.3gp"));
parameters.title = "video title";
parameters.description = "video description";
dynamic result = fb.Post("/me/videos", parameters);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Sorry didn't get a notification for your response.  I tried this, but I'm getting an 'Invalid oAuth 2.0 Token' response back - yet I can publish a Photo or Status message with no problems?

Comment: Note to self: when copying and pasting parameters.access_token, actually change the value! ;)